# "Unhandled exception while executing query: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'encode'" when running a Postgres function

Tags: sql, postgresql

Consider the following Postgres function:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION views_schema.function_name(user_id integer, quiz_id integer)
RETURNS TABLE (title varchar, given_answer varchar, correct BOOLEAN, seconds INTEGER, answered_at TIMESTAMPtz, id int, quiz_id INT)
LANGUAGE SQL AS
$func$
SELECT title, given_answer, correct, seconds, answered_at, psa.id, quiz_id from public.table1 psa
INNER JOIN public.table2 psq ON psq.id = psa.question_id
WHERE user_id = (SELECT user_id from public.table3 where id = $1) AND first = True AND quiz_id = $2
ORDER by created_at DESC
$func$;
```

Running the function like this:

```sql
SELECT views_schema.function_name(598272,872)
```

returns the below message:

```
Started executing query at Line 1
Commands completed successfully
Unhandled exception while executing query: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'encode'
Total execution time: 00:00:00.507
```

What am I missing? Most existing reports for this message that I could find seem to be Python-related errors. In this case I'm simply running plain SQL queries (in Azure Data Studio here). The expected result should be the output of the function (i.e, a table).

Comment: As the function returns a table, try `SELECT * from views_schema.function_name(598272,872)`. Otherwise it returns a record (i.e. "tuple") per row and the high-level language has no "encode" method for it and fails to handle the result.

Comment: That works, @Stefanov.sm. Put yours as an answer and I can mark it as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the function returns a table, try

```sql
SELECT * from views_schema.function_name(598272,872);
```

Otherwise it returns a record (i.e. "tuple") per row. The high-level language has no "encode" method for it and fails to handle the result.

I would go one step further when transferring table-returning query results to a statically-typed language. Wrap the query like this

```sql
SELECT json_agg(to_json(t.*)) from
(
  <the actual query here>
) as t;
```

so that the latter would *always* receive a JSON result and handle it as appropriate. This is however a matter of personal style or taste.